# JOLT Transformation with repeating elements for each inner array

Tags: json, transform, apache-nifi, jolt

I need a JOLT spec to do the below transformation in an Apache NiFi JOLT processor. So there are arrays that are all the same length (in this case 3), and so I want to expand it into 3 records with the non array values repeated. The input data all has the same labels of "text" and so I want to keep it that way after the transform as shown in the expected output.

Input Json:

```
[
  [
    {
      "text": "AAA"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "text": "BBB"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "text": "11"
    },
    {
      "text": "12"
    },
    {
      "text": "13"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "text": "A1"
    },
    {
      "text": "B2"
    },
    {
      "text": "C3"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "text": "Z"
    }
  ]
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
    [
        [
            {
                "text": "AAA"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "BBB"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "11"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "A1"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "Z"
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            {
                "text": "AAA"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "BBB"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "12"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "B2"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "Z"
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            {
                "text": "AAA"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "BBB"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "13"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "C3"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "Z"
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Hi VinceL , excuse me but I couldn't understand which array has length 3 ? There are lots of arrays within the JSON ...

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - all of the arrays come in at the same length. Above, all arrays are size 3. Another record may come in with all of them as size 5. So the need is to first determine that size and then generate that many records with the non array values repeated as shown in the expected output. I answered my own question below with a different solution as I couldn't get JOLT or JSLT to handle the fact that all the keys are named the same ("text"). If someone is able to figure that out, I would consider marking that as the answer as it could be more efficient, but for now, my answer solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I created this question as being JOLT specific for the needed solution, but in reality I really should have phrased the question more generically as that I needed the JSON transformed somehow using NiFi.

I was pointed to JSLT as another transform NiFi processor that I was unaware of, but I was not successful in that either. The main problem for both of those attempts, was that all of the JSON key/value pairs all have the same key name of "text" and I could not get transform definitions to handle that. This is how my source comes in and so I needed a way to handle that.

In the end, I created used a Groovy script processor that uses Regex matching loops to identify the size that is common to all of the arrays, extract the array values while repeating the non array values, and generate the needed records based off of that. Below is the script:

```
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.*

def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->

def ffcontent = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   
def rcrd = ""

//First find if there are arrays
def p = /\[\{\"text\":[^\[]*\}\,\{[^\[]*\}\]/
def m = ffcontent =~ p

if(m.count>0) //m.count is number of arrays - if it is equal to 0, flowfile passes through unchanged
{    
    //next, find array size (arrays are all the same size,
    //so only need to check first one)    
    def ap = /\{\"text\":(?:(?!\}\,\{|\}\]\,\[\{).)*\}/
    def am = m[0] =~ ap
    def arraySize = am.count

    rcrd = rcrd + "["
    //then loop number of array size times:    
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) 
    {        
        //loop through every item (both single and arrays)
        rcrd = rcrd + "["
        def ip = /\[\{\"text\":[^\[]*[^\[]*\}\]/
        def im = ffcontent =~ ip
        for (int j = 0; j < im.count; j++) 
        {
            //now check if single or array item
            def ai = im[j] =~ ap
            if(ai.count > 1) //array item
            {
                //array, so pick the ith value                
                rcrd = rcrd + "[" + ai[i] + "]";
            }
            else //single item
            {
                rcrd = rcrd + im[j];
            }
            if(j < im.count - 1)
            {
                rcrd = rcrd + ","
            }
        }
        rcrd = rcrd + "]"
        if(i < arraySize-1)
        {
            rcrd = rcrd + ","
        }
    }
    rcrd = rcrd + "]"
    ffcontent = rcrd
}
        
    outputStream.write(ffcontent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JSLT instead of JOLT? May be easier for this task.

https://github.com/schibsted/jslt/tree/master

You can use it with JSLTTransformJSON.

Comment: I did not know about JSLT so thanks for that info. I am open to using that since there is a NiFi processor for it. I am going through documentation and examples trying to figure out how to apply it to this problem, but so far have not been able to figure out how to do the splitting of the records to match the array size.